# Reading client-side value of <p:selectOneMenu/> in onchange callback

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

Given this:

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selection}" onchange="handleChange();">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="bar" itemValue="1"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleChange() {
        // Do something here...
    }
</script>
```

How do I detect the selected item in JavaScript so I can take appropriate action (e.g. show/hide a div) in the `handleChange()` function? There doesn't appear to be any documentation for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selected value is in the HTML DOM event attribute available by `this.value`.

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selection}" onchange="handleChange(this.value)">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="bar" itemValue="1"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleChange(selection) {
        // Do something here with selection...
    }
</script>
```

---

> *There doesn't appear to be any documentation for this.*

This is not specific to JSF, but to HTML/JS in general, so the answer ought to be found by looking at the JSF-generated HTML output in the client side and understanding some basic HTML/JS.

Comment: Thanks. And you're right, because I did just that and came up with the same answer after asking the question. Still, it would be *nice* for this to be included in the PrimeFaces documentation.